# DatePicker. Как получить данные корректно

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет!
У меня есть класс ToDoItem

```
    class ToDoItem with ChangeNotifier {
  final String id;
  final DateTime creationDate;
  final DateTime doingDate;
  final String text;
  final Color color;

  ToDoItem({this.id, this.creationDate, this.doingDate, this.text, this.color});
}
```

Есть DatePicker в statefull виджете

```
    class _TopWithDateAndOptionState extends State<TopWithDateAndOption> {
      var finaldate;
      void callDatePicker() async {
       var order = await getDate();
       setState(() {
       finaldate = order;
       print("pickeddate = ${finaldate}");
     });
              }

 

     Future<DateTime> getDate() {
        // Imagine that this function is
        // more complex and slow.
        return showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(2018),
          lastDate: DateTime(2030),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
            return Theme(
              data: ThemeData.light(),
              child: child,
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

В конце я получаю объект класса ToDoItem через Provider.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final todoItem = Provider.of<ToDoItem>(context);
```

Как правильно теперь организовать изменение в todoItem? Мне нужно знать, когда finaldate действительно получил новые данные, чтоб через todoItem.refresh(finaldata) (саму функцию еще не написал)?

Answer (score 0):

И в чем проблема?

```
if(finaldate != null) {
  todoItem.refresh(finaldata);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Если автор даст больше объяснений и суть проблемы, то я смогу дать более развернутый ответ. Пока здесь больше абстракции, чем конкретики...